# Send data on click - jQuery ajax chat

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, livechat

I have a jQuery chat with script

```
var name = "Guest";
    name = name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    var chat =  new Chat();
    $(function() {
         chat.getState();
         $("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {
             var key = event.which;
             if (key >= 33) {
                 var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
                 var length = this.value.length;
                 if (length >= maxLength) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                 }
              }
              });
         $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                var text = $(this).val();
                var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
                var length = text.length;
                if (length <= maxLength + 1) {
                    chat.send("testtext", name);
                    $(this).val("");
                } else {
                    $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
                }
              }
         });
    });
```

the html structure is;

```
<body onload="setInterval('chat.update()', 1000)">

    <div id="page-wrap">
    
        <h2>jQuery/PHP Chat</h2>
        
        <p id="name-area"></p>
        
        <div id="chat-wrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>
        
        <form id="send-message-area">
            <p>Your message: </p>
            <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '100' ></textarea>
            <button id="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    
    </div>

</body>
```

This send (or save to file) message when I hit `ENTER` key after my message. I have replaced text area data with `testtext`. I want to send data when I click the `submit` button.

How can I do this?

I am trying to modify **[this](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/)** example. I am trying to add a button instead of default `enter` key hit.

Comment: is there any way if i take `<button id="submit">submit</button>
` outside form??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing `chat send` from main group and included it in `trigger click function` as below;

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    chat.send("testtext", name);
    $(this).val("");
    });
```

Thanks to @Kon, @Piotr Salaciak and @Dutchie432 for their support... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).  For example:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: myUrl,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json", 
      data: { 'message' : $('#sendie').val() }, 
      success: function(data){
        //...
      },
      error: function(e, xhr){
        //...
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes it possible?  Yes.  Am I going to do it for you?  If you pay me...  Figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fire event when submiting a form:

```
$('#sendie').keyup(function(e, extra) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || extra.keyCode == 13) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
        var length = text.length;
        if (length <= maxLength + 1) {
            chat.send("testtext", name);
            $(this).val("");
        } else {
            $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
        }
    }
 });
```

...

```
$("#send-message-area").submit(){
    $('#sendie').trigger('keyup', [{keyCode: 13}]);
    return false;
}
```

the line `return false` is needed to prevent from reloading Your page.

**After update** Added a new parameter to `keyup` function named `extra`, which will hold the keyCode for event fired "manually".

Comment: This would only work if you could pass the keycode `13` as well (maybe you can?), in order to ensure the desired code fires.

Comment: Again.. not sure if that will work since the function is expecting an event, and not a variable called `keyCode`. Can you make this work? http://jsfiddle.net/kV7qL/1/

Comment: @Dutchie432 I though that second parameter of `trigger` function will override the first parameter of raised event, but it doesn't. Event is always the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the code from `$('#sendie').keyup()`, create a function and call it from `$('#sendie').keyup()` and `$('#send-message-area').submit()`

something like this

```
var name = "Guest";
name = name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
var chat =  new Chat();
$(function() {
     chat.getState();
     $("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {
         var key = event.which;
         if (key >= 33) {
             var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
             var length = this.value.length;
             if (length >= maxLength) {
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
          }
          });
     $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
             doSend();
             return (false);
          }
     });
     $('#send-message-area').submit(function(e) {
        doSend();
        return (false);
    });
});

function doSend(){
    var text = $('#sendie').val();
    var maxLength = $('#sendie').attr("maxlength");
    var length = text.length;
    if (length <= maxLength + 1) {
        chat.send("testtext", name);
        $('#sendie').val("");
    } else {
        $('#sendie').val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
    }
}
```